# How do I count the occurrences of multiple and different letters within a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, count, counter

Example:

If I want to write code to determine how many occurrences of a particular character appear in a string, how would I do that for multiple characters?
For example if I have these words, lets just say "Simple Example" and I want to find how many times the letter E exists inside these words, I would probably use something like:

example = "Simple Example".count("e")

But what if I wanted to find more letters than just e? Let's say I want to find the occurrences of the letters that exist within the word "awesome"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on an input of `awesome` what is the output you want?

Comment: You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is a `dict` subclass meaning that you can easily access count by using a key (which in case of a string will be the character).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use `counter`, the best way perhaps would be:

```
import collections

a = "example"
counter = collections.Counter(a)

print(dict(counter))
# {'e': 2, 'x': 1, 'a': 1, 'm': 1, 'p': 1, 'l': 1}
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: yeah, just thought i should post some content if i’m writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension:

```
letters = ['e', 'm']
["Simple Example".count(letter) for letter in letters]
```

Comment: there is a [slight issue regarding `count`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600208/14531062) tho I am not sure how it affects strings but I would guess that the effect is similar

Comment: @Matiiss It takes quite a few characters to count before this gets slower than Counter.

Answer (score -1):

This should suffice the requirement.

```
a = {}
s = "awesome"
{a.update({i:s.count(i)}) for i in s if i not in a}
print(a)
```